# Display available VIM commands using <tab>

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a way to display commands using tab? By commands, I don't mean bash ones, but vim ones, using **:**

For instance :
I use Nerdtree plugin by typing ':' in NORMAL mode (:NERDTree). If I tab NER, I directly have NERDTree. Then in I tab again > NERDTreeCWD > NERDTreeClose > NERDTreeFind etc...

Is it possible to display all the available commands somehow in the status bar?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for `<C-d>`? This will show you all possible completions of the current command. 
See `:help cmdline-completion`.

Comment: <C-d> does work indeed. But can we doing it with tab ?
For example, I begin typing my command, then I tab, all commands are displayed, and the selected one (by tab) is highlighted ?

Comment: Ah okay, try entering :set wildmenu, and then using normal tab completion.
See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/is-there-a-version-of-vim-or-plugin-with-a-command-mode-auto-completion

Comment: Well, it does exacly what I asked ! Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome :). 
Also, as seen on the other page. :set wildmode=list:full, gives you a display of all completions, whilst simultaneously showing you the currently selected completion. Sadly not in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Rinceldor for your answer, that was helpful. By the way, if you want to use `Tab` key to display available commands, you must add `cnoremap <Tab> <C-L><C-D>` into your `~/.vimrc` file.
It will replace two keystrokes is `Ctrl + L` and `Ctrl + D` with the `Tab` key.